# Problema con el cambio de valor de un input type text

Tags: html

¿ Como puedo modificar el valor asignado en html al siguiente input type text ?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-right o-decimal-number" id="input-tipoiva"   name="tipoiva" value="{{$factura->tipodeiva}}"tabindex="5" maxlength="5" size="5">
```

Está incluido en un form y al darle otro valor y validar  continúa manteniendo el value="{{$factura->tipodeiva}}"

Espero haberme explicado mejor

Comment: La verdad es que leí tu pregunta pero no entiendo nada, ¿puedes proveer una mejor explicación basándote en [ask]?

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente. Mejora la pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cómo validas el valor? Si utilizas un botón con `type=submit` lo que estará ocurriendo es que se envía el valor que has introducido pero al recargar la página vuelve a poner el valor por defecto que le indicas en el html. Si es esto lo que ocurre puedes cambiar el tipo del boton pero siempre que recargues la página aparecerá el valor indicado en el html. Para que aparezca otro tendrías que hacerlo con javascript.

Comment: A la atención de Miguel27: valido mediante ajax

Comment: A la atención de Sergio Gordillo: Lo que pretendo hacer es cambiar el valor de un  input text predeterminado, por por un nuevo valor

Comment: Para que los usuarios sean notificados cuando les respondes debes usar `@` seguido del nombre del usuario. Si pones *A la atención de ....*  no serán notificados. Dicho eso, falta explicar el contexto de la pregunta. Usa el editor de código para poner un ejemplo completo que podamos probar, donde se intente cambiar el valor del `input`
 y no ocurra. Si usas algun framework o biblioteca también deberías decirlo. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @A. Cedano El problema era que habían dos id con la misma denominación ,lamento las molestias.